# Magento 2 Account Sharing issue

Tags: magento2, customer-account, customer-session

I am trying to setup account sharing globally on our Magento 2 installation.
The setting, under **STORES-> Configuration-> Customers-> Customer Configuration**, for Account Sharing Options is set to Global.
I created a user on site A, `shared@account.com`, and I am able to login to site A successfully.  Once logging out of site A, I open site B in a new tab (also tried different browser) and try to login with the `shared@account.com` credentials, but get the "**Invalid login or password**" error.
Any thoughts on why this is not working properly?